# angular6 not refresh css change

Tags: angular6

I have done a small change in a css file, rebuild the project and deploy it.
However I can not see the change.

What I am doing wrong or missing in the building process?

Some help will be really appreacite.
Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
"development": {
                            "outputPath": "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/project/public",
                            "baseHref": "https://example.org/",
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true
                        },
```

environment.dev.ts

```
export const environment = {
    apiUrl: 'https://example.org/',
    loginUrl: 'https://example.org/notice.php',
    indexUrl: 'https://example.org/',
    assestHost: 'https://example.org/',
    production: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had a problem doing the merge.